# How to configure Nginx to return a CSV as response?

Tags: php, laravel, csv, ubuntu, nginx

I have a `test.csv` file locate at the root of my VM running on Ubuntu. 
I am using `Nginx` in `Laravel 4.2`.

[image]

- VM IP : `1.1.1.1`
- Domain : `www.site.com`

How do I make that CSV public accessible via my site: `www.site.com/csv`  ?

**nginx**

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    root /home/forge/john/public;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location /nginx_status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location /resume {
        #auth_basic "Restricted";
        #auth_basic_user_file /home/forge/john/.htpasswd;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /getIconBasedOnDevicesName {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your question in particular how to serve a file located in root? Otherwise check the documentation for file downloads: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-downloads

Comment: Is it a way to do it via nginx instead of Laravel ?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is located at `/home/forge/john/public/test.csv`, you could use:

```
location = /csv {
    try_files /test.csv =404;
}
```

Comment: I have try that, but the Laravel route seem to take effect ontop of that. : https://i.imgur.com/zQ2rvwg.png